Stochastic boundedness in consistency proof
I'm reading Knight and Fu (2000), Asymptotics for Lasso-Type Estimators and I don't understand why (6) and (7) imply consistency in Theorem 1 (copied and pasted below).
I'm familiar with the standard Newey and McFadden conditions for consistency — compactness, uniform convergence in probability of $Z_n$ to $Z$ (this is equation  6 here), continuity of $Z$, and $Z$ has a unique minimizer — and I'm aware that they can be substantially weakened. But I've never seen a condition like (7) on the minimizer of $Z_n$.


(6) is uniform convergence in probability on every compact set. (7) implies there is some fixed compact set $K$  that contains $\hat\beta_n$ with high probability for all large enough $n$.
More specifically, given $\epsilon>0$, there is a compact $K_\epsilon$ and an $N$ such that for any $n>N$ $P(\hat\beta_n\in K_\epsilon)>1-\epsilon$
So, you can fix a compact set $K_\epsilon$ and apply your familiar uniform convergence argument to show that $\hat\beta_n$ converges to the desired limit along any subsequence that stays in $K_\epsilon$.
Now $$P(\|\hat\beta_n- \arg\min Z\|>\epsilon)< P\left(\|\hat\beta_n- \arg\min Z\|>\epsilon \mid \hat\beta_n\in K_\epsilon
\right)P(\hat\beta_n\in K_\epsilon)+ P(\hat\beta_n \not\in K_\epsilon)$$
The first term is small for large $n$ because of uniform convergence over $K_\epsilon$ and the second by the choice of $K_\epsilon$.
